# Wrapping socket connections

Tags: openssh, socket

I'd like to wrap an insecure connection (this one: http://culturedcode.com/things/) with a secure tunnel, a bit like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stunnel does, just using UNIX tools.

What's the best way to intercept insecure traffic, encrypt it and deliver it to the insecure socket at the other end of the communication channel?

I am used to wrapping/tunnelling VNC connections using SSH port forwarding, how would you do something to the same effect with an application such as Things for Mac/iPhone? Namely: a generic application using known ports to exchange unencrypted data?

Bonus points for step-by-step instructions ;)

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use stunnel? Either I didn't understand what you're trying to do, or it looks like the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at ncat (which is part of nmap).

```
ncat -l 80 -c "ncat (ip-address) (port) --ssl"
```

For more information see: [Using ncat to provide SSL-support to non-ssl capable software](http://louwrentius.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-ncat-to-provide-ssl-support-to.html)